# Job change under outsourcing

Tags: professionalism, job-change, outsourcing

I'm working under outsourcing in company B hired by company A.

I was hired to be developer for X language, but I'm instead working with  platform/tools Y (that uses X language, but until now I haven't done anything with it).

When I was hired, they never asked if I had experience or knowledge of the platform Y.

I was assigned 2 tasks on which I couldn't deliver, since they didn't provide training nor proper details, my coworkers couldn't help and everything seems to need a license and any training material is behind a paywall.

How I can ask for transfer to another company, when I was hired to work specifically with company B?

Comment: Do you know if there are openings at other companies? How long have you been working there? Would you keep working there if you can't transfer? Do you report to anyone from company A?

Comment: Start looking for a new job.

Comment: @Dukeling yes there is other openings at other companies,- i have almost 3 months working ,- only until next year, i'm a bit in need of money so i will try do my best to avoid being fired, - no i don't report directly  to A, only in special cases (sick days, vacations thos kind of stuff)

Comment: If you know X and Y uses X then you should be able to handle Y without any problems.  It sounds like you overstated your qualifications to be honest.  Calling a spade a spade.

Answer (score 1):

> How I can ask for transfer to another company, when I was hired to work specifically with company B?

First I suggest that you explain your situation to your manager in company B, so he can decide what to do about the training or your assigned tasks. Maybe they didn't *provide* the training you need, but you can sure *ask for it* if you consider that absolutely necessary. Best case they provide you with training material and problem solved.

If this does not work and you still feel like looking for other job you should go for it. In that case, given that company A put you to work there, you can try approaching them with your request to be transfered (that is, if you still wish to be hired by A). They can either do so or deny your request.

You could also try approaching your manager on company B for other positions they may have that you could apply.

Alternatively, you can try approaching the other companies you are interested in personally, in case you wish not continue hired by company A as an outsource resource.

In any case you want to keep your options open. Before approaching any manager try doing some research on your own first, and also make sure the current training issue has no solution before deciding to go for a new job.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to first do some research on ones own about the opportunities available before approaching ones manager about it. If there aren't other opportunities you're interested in, approaching them can only do harm. Applying to a company which A outsources for may come back to bite you if A just handles all applicants, there's some sort of shared applicant database or they figure out that it's company A and they just feel like telling them.

Comment: @Dukeling true, it is better to do some research on your own first before attempting any move. Editing answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So in short you are employed by company A, but do all your work directly for company B through an outsourcing contract. 
In essence you no longer want to be employed by A, but directly by B.

The usual procedure is to apply directly to company B and hope they make you an offer. There is really not much more one can say about this in general. If you know someone inside company B, you could try to speak to them directly, but that would be company specific.

A little advice: also apply to company C,D,E ... and so on. Company B probably won´t hire you, or else they would have to admit their outsourcing strategy failed.

Comment: "So in short you work for company A and want to work for company B. " - I think this is not what OP meant ...

Comment: Still, I think that OP meant he is actually working for A but they sent him as outsourcing to work on company B

Comment: `i'm working under outsourcing in company B hired by company A.`

Comment: @DarkCygnus: I clarified it - thank you for pointing out it was a little bit ambiguous.

Comment: @Daniel it's ok, I also had to read it a couple times to get it right ;)

Comment: I think you have your A's and B's a little mixed up in the second and third paragraphs (or did you mean C, i.e. the "another company" in the question?). OP doesn't want to work for company B any more.

Comment: @Dukeling: No, as I read it, OP is legally an employee of company A. He is send off to do work at company B. So B will not invest in him, because he is not employed there and A will not invest in him because that would only reduce their ROI.

Comment: In that case, B could be legally prohibited from hiring OP (thanks to their agreement with A) or they just likely wouldn't want to (if not because they chose to go through A in the first place, then because OP's performance so far was lacklustre, thanks to their lack of training). I don't think we should jump to conclusions about who is and isn't willing to invest in OP, it's better to ask (the contract may be long enough for either party to justify investing in training).

Comment: @Dukeling: ... *since they didn't provide training* ... not jumping to conclusions, just summing up what I understood from OP. Other than that, I agree with you, that OP will not get a chance to hire at B directly. Hence, I recommended that he look entirely elsewhere (C,D,E ... ). These outsourcing providers tend to leave people frustrated.